# Is contentDocument.location.reload compatible with IE 6

Tags: javascript

I'm busy writing a application that refreshes a IFrame completely using javascript, now my issue is that I'm getting the following error in IE 6

```
'document.getElementById(...).contentDocument.location' is null or not an object
```

My code looks like this

```
document.getElementById('mobi').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

and mobi exist. mobi is the id of an iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use contentWindow for old IE :)

document.getElementById('mobi').contentWindow.location.reload(true);

(read more about [contentWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533692%28VS.85%29.aspx))